# How do I store an array in Firefox from a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, firefox, greasemonkey

I am updating [a Greasemonkey script which reads the name of the `href` in the list of ignored users in the ignore section of *vBulletin*](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/88463).

I store the values in an array and then `display:none` to the `td` which will hide the ignored users thread from the message board.

The only way to do this is to visit the ignore list and store the array values in `about:config`. But I can't get the array to store there.

Here is the relevant part of the updated script:

```
// @grant          GM_setValue 
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    var allT; 
    var allR;
    var plonk = new Array(); 
    var ignore_threads_from = GM_setValue;

    var url = "http://www.site.com/forums/profile.php?do=ignorelist"; //use for iggy list URL
    var currentURL = window.location;

    if (url == currentURL) {
        var GM_setValue = $('#ignorelist.userlist li a').map(function() {
              return $(this).text();
        }).get();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to convert the array to a string, `JSON.stringify()` is best for that.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
GM_setValue("key", JSON.stringify(a));

var b = JSON.parse(GM_getValue("key"));
```

This is assuming `plonk` is not an array of elements -- there is no hint as to what you are doing there.

Why are you overwriting GM_setValue?  Leave that alone.

Comment: Here is the source i am editing. Basically you see where they have the array ignore_threads_from, i just want to store my own array of values in place of that. http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/88463

Comment: Yes, the code sample you linked to is just storing strings, so code I posted will load and save those arrays.  Exactly where they get saved, however, can differ with each user-script implementation.

Comment: what does the 3rd line do? and why do i need it?

Comment: The third line `var b...` is what you use to reload the data that was saved in line 2.  (At least will be, as soon as I fix a typo.

Comment: Yeah... i assume that should have been called  var a ??

Comment: Well originally the array values were stored in : `ignore_threads_from` so var b must be called ignore_threads_from

Comment: My code example came before you posted the source you were referring.      But yes, you do need to use the correct variable names. I was just showing the syntax needed.

Comment: Its really frustrating, when i get about:config nothing is storing. i called it "keykey" and it didnt show up. any ideas?

Comment: Yes.  **`Ignore about:config`**  GreaseMonkey has been through a lot of changes since Version 1 and believe that the new GreaseMonkey saves its data somewhere in an internal database.  You don't need to know where it goes -- just how to put it there `GM_setValue` and how to get it back `GM_getValue`.  Knowing how to turn things into a string `JSON.stringify` and turn them back into an object/array `JSON.parse` is just icing on the cake to make the whole thing easier.

Comment: well im going to bed now... seems like a heap of hassle to do this.. guess im learning, and thats what matters! thanks for all your guidance today! :)

Comment: This answer was generally right, but that comment about ignoring `about:config` is wrong.  Greasemonkey still stores `GM_setValue` values in the same manner, which means you should see them in `about:config`.  The only exception is still rare and does not apply to this question.

Comment: @BrockAdams -- Ah, it is Chrome's `TamperMonkey` that stores the values in a DB.   Seems [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scriptish/?src=search) uses about:config too.  Thanks for the correction there.

Answer (score 6):

Jeremy J Starcher's answer is correct in that:

1. You can't store arrays that way, using `GM_setValue()`.
2. The question code was using `GM_setValue()` incorrectly anyway, and overwriting the function! (`var GM_setValue = ...`).

Additional things to know:

1. `GM_setValue()` and `GM_getValue()` do an abysmal job with anything other than strings.  But, fortunately, several utilities exist to correct the deficiencies.  A good one is [Super_GM_setValue_and_GM_getValue.js](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/107941).

   To use this, add this line to your script's [metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block):

   ```
   // @require http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/107941.user.js
   ```
2. Be sure you also `@grant` `GM_getValue` and `GM_setValue` in your metadata block.
3. There is no point in wrapping the code in an anonymous function, EG:

   ```
   (function() {
       ...
   })();
   ```
4. Use `window.location.href`, not `window.location`.

**Putting it all together, that code snippet would be like:**

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/107941.user.js
// @grant   GM_setValue 
// @grant   GM_getValue 
// ==/UserScript==

var allT; 
var allR;
var plonk               = new Array(); 
var ignore_threads_from = GM_SuperValue.get ("IgnoredUsers", []);

var url         = "http://www.example.com/forums/profile.php?do=ignorelist"; //use for iggy list URL
var currentURL  = window.location.href;

if (url == currentURL) {
    var ignoreList  = $('#ignorelist.userlist li a').map (function () {
          return $(this).text();
    } ).get ();

    GM_SuperValue.set ("IgnoredUsers", ignoreList);
}
```